# Trying to create eks cluster using eksctl with ssh-access

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, pem, amazon-eks, eksctl

While creating eks cluster using EKSCTL it is throwing error like `error decoding SSH public key`

Permission of pem file is 400

Command i am executing

`eksctl create cluster --name=thirdekscluster --ssh-access --ssh-public-key=mysshkey.pem --nodegroup-name=standard-workers --node-type=t3.medium --nodes=3 --nodes-min=1 --nodes-max=4 --node-ami=auto`

Error:

```
[ℹ]  using region ap-south-1
[ℹ]  setting availability zones to [ap-south-1a ap-south-1c ap-south-1b]
[ℹ]  subnets for ap-south-1a - public:xxxxx/19 private:xxxx/19
[ℹ]  subnets for ap-south-1c - public:xxxxx/19 private:xxxx/19
[ℹ]  subnets for ap-south-1b - public:xxxxx/19 private:xxxx/19
[ℹ]  nodegroup "standard-workers" will use "ami-01b6a163133c31994" [AmazonLinux2/1.12]
[✖]  computing fingerprint for key "mysshkey.pem": 
error decoding SSH public key: 

"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" 

err: illegal base64 data at input byte 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your response, but i sorted out myself.

```
created cluster using - eksctl create cluster --name=thirdekscluster --ssh-access=true --ssh-public-key=sreeeks --nodegroup-name=standard-workers --node-type=t3.medium --nodes=3 --nodes-min=1 --nodes-max=4 --node-ami=auto
```

The SSH part in the command should be like `--ssh-access=true`

Comment: it works as well with `--ssh-access`, without `=true` part

Answer (score 3):

I had the same ploblem, in my case I was trying to use the private key instead of public. (key was created directly on aws ec2 console panel)

**Solution:**
ssh-keygen -y -f .pem >> <> .pem (just an ilustrative name).

Answer (score 1):

I used Bitvise Client Key Management to export in OpenSSH format. After that, eksctl worked!

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked as I removed the BOM by copying the public key to a different txt file.

Answer (score -1):

```
eksctl create cluster --ssh-access --ssh-public-key=~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub --nodegroup-name=standard-workers --node-type=t3.medium --nodes=2 --nodes-min=1 --nodes-max=2
```

This should definitely work.

Comment: Would you comment on your command line syntax? Particularly how does it differ to the one by @Sreejith?